# CSS3 transitions seem to need a "warmup" time before they kick off? Do I have to add a wait?

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

I have a CSS3 transition where I shrink the height of an element. I'm doing this by:

1. CSS3 transition and destination height specified on class (e.g. height:5px in class)
2. Assign height=$el.height() to element in style attribute (e.g. height:100px on style)
3. Add class to element
4. Remove the height defined in style attribute
5. Computed CSS value changes from style's 100px to class's 5px, which triggers a transition

What I'm discovering is that there seems to be a delay on setting the CSS3 transition trigger, and if step #4 is done too soon after #3, the trigger will see that height is initially auto instead of 100px, and no transition happens (due to another limitation of CSS3, you can't transition from height:auto to height:x).

Here's the actual code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $a = $('#box'); // height:auto, not specified
  $a.css('height',$a.height()); // height:100px on style;
  $a.addClass('shrink'); // height:100px on style, height:5px on class
  $a.css('height',''); // height removed from style, falls back to 5px on class
});
```

Here's a JSFiddle demonstrating the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/1escyLqf/2/

In the fiddle, if I add a delay of 20ms before removing the height value, the transition works. If you comment that line out and call css('height','') immediately after adding the class, it's too fast and no transition happens.

Is this a bug in browser implementation of CSS3 transitions? Or do I really need to add in a timeout?

Comment: Probably best to avoid the class and just set the height directly. Transitioning from / to `auto` never works

Comment: Check out the jsfiddle - it works (because we're setting the height to $el.height() as a workaround). The timing is the only issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague helped me out with the following solution, which calls an offset between the addClass() and the css() height-reset:

```
$a.addClass('shrink');
$a.offset();
$a.css('height','');
```

This forces a redraw after addClass(), and ensures that the class addition (and transition set-up) occurs before the height change.

http://jsfiddle.net/1escyLqf/3/

Answer (score 0):

Create this with CSS3 animation appended in the jQuery with a dynamic starting height.

#### The jQuery

1. Get the boxes height:

   ```
   var boxHeight = $('#box').height();
   ```
2. Create your animation and apply it to the shrink class. Get the starting height from the variable.

   ```
   var animation = '
   <style type="text/css">
       .shrink { 
          -webkit-animation: shrink 12s forwards; 
          animation: shrink 12s forwards; 
        } 

        @-webkit-keyframes shrink { 
            0% { 
               height:' + boxHeight + 'px; 
               } 
            100% { 
               height: 5px; 
            } 
        } 
        @keyframes shrink { 
            0% { 
               height:' + boxHeight + 'px; 
               } 
            100% { 
               height: 5px; 
            } 
        }
   </style>';
   ```
3. Append the style to the `<head>`

   ```
   $('head').append(animation);
   ```

### Complete Example

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var boxHeight = $('#box').height();
  
  var animation = '<style type="text/css"> .shrink { -webkit-animation: shrink 12s forwards; animation: shrink 12s forwards; } @-webkit-keyframes shrink { 0% { height:' + boxHeight + 'px; } 100% { height: 5px; } } @keyframes shrink { 0% { height:' + boxHeight + 'px; } 100% { height: 5px; } }</style>';
  
  $('head').append(animation);
});
```

```css
#box,
#box2 {
  background: red;
  margin: 10px;
}
.shrink {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box" class="shrink">
  <p>make height</p>
  <p>make height</p>
  <p>make height</p>
  <p>make height</p>
</div>
```